# Change single axis in plotly subplots

Tags: python, plot, plotly, plotly-python

I generated a plot in plotly using plotly.express. I used a pandas.DataFrame and one column to differentiate the two subplots putting it into facet_row
Now my data has very different scales they are operating one, but plotly assigns the same range to both yaxis.
I've tried to assign a 'range' attribute to the .layout.yaxis1 dictionary (using a list), but this changes the yaxis for both the upper and the lower plot.
Minimal working example:

```
import plotly.express as px    
px.bar(pd.DataFrame({'x':[50,60,45,.80],'y': [800,900,1,2],"dif":['a','a','b','b']}),x='x',y='y',facet_row='dif')
```

How can I change the first axis alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `.update_yaxes(matches=None)` that will break the linkage between the Y-axis ranges.

This works because `px.bar()` (and any other `px.*()`) returns a `Figure` object which are are updatable via various `.update_*()` methods. These methods mutate and return the figure. `px.bar(facet_row="whatever")` by default sets the `yxaxis*.matches` attribute to `y1` and so clearing that via `.update_yaxes()` will get the behaviour you want.

After that you can set the range independently however you like.

More information here: https://plot.ly/python/creating-and-updating-figures/